# How did the merger of Draftkings (DKNG) affect my holdings?

Tags: stocks

I am a beginner investor for stocks. Last year I bought Draftkings stock 220 @ $68.00 but after merger with Golden Nugget on May 4 2022. My share Cost changed from $68 to $14.44.
My 220 shares didn't changed only Cost is down to $14.44
I tried to figure it out and understand the merger rules. but I couldn't find the answer.
I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Are you certain it's the _cost basis_ and not the current value that's changed? The acquisition (not merger) did not adjust DKNG's stock that I can see.

Comment: My cost was $68/share for 220 last year when I bought it. This morning when I checked my account, I realized my cost was $14.44/share with same amounts of shares. It didn't stock split how come my cost per share was changed with same amounts of share? This is my question.

Comment: Do you mean _cost_ or _current value_? Does it show how much profit or loss you have? I bet you're looking at the current value, not what you pad for it.

Comment: I'm using Questrade for Canadian. Avg price is the cost value for purchasing. It shows Avg price $14.44 and qty 220. symbol price (current price) is $11.84

Answer (score 6):

Draft Kings acquired (not merged with) Golden Nugget, so the share price was not directly adjusted. Your shares (and the cost basis) should not have changed.

Draft kings hasn't traded higher than $65 in the past 12 months, and has steadily declined from that high to under $12 now.

You did not lose money because of the acquisition (well, not directly - the acquisition could have been considered a failure); you lost money because the share price has declined steadily over the last year.

Comment: Also my understanding is the cost basis shouldn't  change it. My cost basis is from $68 to $14.44  with same amounts of share.  I didn't  buy or sell more DKNG stocks after purchased it.

Comment: @jeffk -- your cost basis is the amount that you paid for the stock. That's all. Later changes in value don't affect what you paid, so your cost basis is still $68.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same thing with my account and I use Questrade too. They changed the average price to $14.44 yet I bought the shares for $28.15. I'm currently on a chat with Questrade and the agent said "I am afraid we currently do not have the detailed reason as to why the merger caused this discrepancy." At any rate, they are going to change the average price back to what I actually purchased the stock at. At least it will now show the accurate information.